# Matlab legend for two plots only applies to second plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to plot data of two vectors, and want the data points of each to be shown in a different colour that is explaned in a legend. However, the code below displays only the legend for the second one. What am I doing wrong?

```
for i_plot = 1 : plot_step : N
    subplot(N, 1, i_plot)
    h_A = plot(bookmarksA(i_plot, :),0,'b.','MarkerSize',24);
    legend('a');
    xlim ([0 pieceDuration])
    set(gca, 'yTick', []);
    title(subj_string(i_plot,:))
    hold on
    h_Z = plot(bookmarksZ(i_plot, :),0,'r.','MarkerSize',24);
    legend(h_Z, 'z');
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only passing one label / handle combination to the `legend` command at a time. For a given axes, each call to `legend` overrides previous calls to `legend`, deleting previous legends rather than adding to an existing legend. You'll want to call `legend` *once* with *both* plot handles and labels.

```
legend([h_A, h_Z], {'a', 'z'})
```

**Update**

Since in your case `h_A` and `h_Z` are arrays of plot handles with identical appearances, you can just pass the first item from `h_A` and `h_Z` to `legend`.

```
legend([h_A(1), h_Z(1)], {'a', 'z'})
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually the line I had used int he first place, but it gives me the error "Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent". This in turn is due to there being different number of data points in each of the two vectors, such that their respective handles (h_A and h_Z) have and 3 and  7 elements respectively. Can a Legend not be created un such cases or do I just need another workaround?

Comment: @z8080 Do all of the plot objects in `h_A` and `h_Z` have the same appearance? If so you could do `legend([h_A(1), h_Z(1)], {'a', 'z'})`